# How to interpret WSDL to create XML SOAP requests manually?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

Using SOAP UI, I have created XML requests. But, How do I find out the value of 'type' attribute and what information to send in the XML generated?

I'm working on the following VMware Site Recovery Manager(SRM) WSDL: https://pastebin.com/5y2TxBg1

For example, in the following request(generated using SOAP UI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:srm0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetApiVersion>
         <urn:_this type=?>?</urn:_this>
      </urn:GetApiVersion>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I find out what should replace the question mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got on the provided link is just the `WSDL` file, which is only the technical part of the documentation of the [service contract](http://serviceorientation.com/soaglossary/service_contract) of this web service. You can, of course, understand some of the requirements for the inputs to this service from this file alone, (like mandatory fields, field types, etc) but the logic behind the a field's usage is not in the `WDSL`.

A properly documented web service should also have a human-readable documentation defining the service inputs, outputs, expected use and performance - the `SLA`.

[image: Service Contract]

The documentation in question in this case [is located here](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/srm-api/) - Site Recovery Manager API Documentation. I'd refer to it in order to understand what is expected as input in more detail.

Hope this helps!